# Stop on error when executing Rmarkdown chunk

Tags: r, error-handling, r-markdown

I'm using RStudio 1.4 and R 3.6.3. When I execute a single code chunk in a Rmarkdown document (ie I press "Run Current Chunk", or use the Ctrl+Shift+Enter shortcut) it does not stop on errors. Is it possible to make it stop?

For instance, if I run the following chunk in an otherwise empty rmd file:

````
```{r, error=TRUE}
stop()
print("A")
```
````

I get the following output in the RStudio console:

```
> stop()
Error: 
> print("A")
[1] "A"
```

I get the same thing if `error = FALSE`.  However, I noticed that having the chunk send output inline makes it stop on the error (but I usually work with output to the console). So it seems to be a RStudio issue, despite the fact that Phil removed that information from the question's title and tags earlier.

Comment: according to the [Rmarkdown CookBook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-error.html) Rmarkdown by default has `error=TRUE` so it should stop automatically if errors are generated inside the R chunk, but you can still explicitly add `error=TRUE` in your Rmarkdown chunk options to try and force the argument

Comment: That does not change anything on my side. I edited my post to give a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

As documented on page 2 of the [R Markdown Reference CheatSheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) the chunk option `error=TRUE` only effects the output of the **knitted** document, i.e. it determines whether the knitting process stops on code errors or continues by showing the error message in the output document.

When running code chunks **within** the R Markdown document, all lines are executed and I am not aware of any option to change this behaviour.